# Merge two separated arrays from `for Loop`

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array below:

```js
const resultthisData = [ [ '7', '8', '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FX', 'KFY', '200' ],
  [ '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FZ', 'MX', 'KFY', '150', 'KMZ', '200' ] ]

for (var i = 0; i < resultthisData.length; i++) {

  var newArray = resultthisData[i].indexOf('FIXED');

  var theLastIndex = resultthisData[i].slice(0, newArray);

  var fixed_Supports = theLastIndex.map(elm => {
    var result_FixedSupports = {
      '0': Number(elm),
      '1': 0

    };

    return result_FixedSupports;

  });

  console.log(fixed_Supports);

}
```

The result is like this

```
[ { '0': 7,'1': 'RFFFFF'},{ '0': 8,'1': 'RFFFFF'},{ '0': 9,'1': 'RFFFFF'}]
[ { '0': 9,'1': 'FFRRFF',} ]
```

How do i combine these two? I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
    [ { '0': 7,'1': 'RFFFFF'},{ '0': 8,'1': 'RFFFFF'},
      { '0': 9,'1':'RFFFFF'}{ '0': 9,'1': 'FFRRFF',} ]
```

How do i combine theme as one array? I can't seem to use `concat`. And now i'm trying to solve it by using push. But i can't figure it out

Comment: `The result is like this` Doesn't look like it - the `'1'` property is always `0`, not a string

Comment: what do you mean by your comment?

Comment: Press "Run code snippet", or just look to your definition of `result_FixedSupports` - there are no strings in the `'1'` property, only a `0`.

Comment: `[...[{ '0': 7,'1': 'RFFFFF'},{ '0': 8,'1': 'RFFFFF'},{ '0': 9,'1': 'RFFFFF'}],...[{ '0': 9,'1': 'FFRRFF',}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your input array has 2 items and your output array has one item, you should probably use `reduce` to reduce into a single array:

```js
const resultthisData = [ [ '7', '8', '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FX', 'KFY', '200' ],
  [ '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FZ', 'MX', 'KFY', '150', 'KMZ', '200' ] ]

const output = resultthisData.reduce((a, subarr) => {
  var newArray = subarr.indexOf('FIXED');
  subarr.slice(0, newArray)
    .forEach(elm => a.push({
      '0': Number(elm),
      '1': 0
    }));
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

`reduce` *is* the proper method to use to transform an array into a single object (including another array that's not one-to-one with the original array), but if you *have* to, you could keep using a `for` loop (which usually isn't a good idea - `for` loops don't offer automatic abstraction, require manual iteration, are not composable, and have hoisting problems when used with `var`:

```js
const resultthisData = [ [ '7', '8', '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FX', 'KFY', '200' ],
  [ '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FZ', 'MX', 'KFY', '150', 'KMZ', '200' ] ]

const output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < resultthisData.length; i++) {
  const subarr = resultthisData[i];
  const newArray = subarr.indexOf('FIXED');
  subarr.slice(0, newArray)
    .forEach(elm => output.push({
      '0': Number(elm),
      '1': 0
    }));
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: is there another way other than reduce? I want to maintain my code above. I am quite confuse about your code. Could you reformat it and based it on my above code? Sorry i'm new to JS

Comment: Ok, I turned it into a `for` loop instead, but `reduce` *really is* the right tool for the job here - the sooner you learn the array methods, the sooner you'll be able to write cleaner, more abstract, higher-order code

Comment: i will try to adapt the foreach soon. But for now i will have to stick with for loop. thank you

Comment: Press Control-M, or press the icon to the right of the Insert Image icon

Comment: here in the comment? How do i do that?

Comment: It's not possible in comments, only in questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested for loops :

```js
const resultthisData = [ [ '7', '8', '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FX', 'KFY', '200' ],
  [ '9', 'FIXED', 'BUT', 'FZ', 'MX', 'KFY', '150', 'KMZ', '200' ] ];
  
  var result = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < resultthisData.length; i++){
    var newArrayLength =  resultthisData[i].indexOf("FIXED");
    for(var j = 0; j < newArrayLength; j++){
        result.push({
          "0" : Number(resultthisData[i][j]),
          "1" : 0
        });
    }
  }
  
  console.log(result);
```